Historical Data read in Thingsboard using API
We have developed the widget card as per attached snapshots, and we are using API method to show values on this card, but card is not able to fetch values in the monthly/yearly average format, it only shows daily live data.
Whereas if we plot similar parameters in the graph using things board built-in time window function, it shows history data.
Please suggest how can we resolve.


We are reading the data over API in array format, but when we try to read historical values it shows NAN.
